# Alternatives to localstorage and session cookies for "remember me" function

Tags: javascript, c#, authentication, remember-me

I am trying to create a remember me feature for my login page.  Everything I have come across incorporates local storage or session cookies. However, I have also come across a few articles that say that using either of this is not good practice. Do any of you have any recommendations on how to tackle this?  This project is done in C#, but I wanted to write it up in JavaScript.

Comment: looks related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34851064/how-to-create-a-remember-me-function-in-login-without-using-form-in-javascript-o

Comment: "_either of this is not good practice_" That's all you have on the client side. You could try to profile the user's browser, and then store the information on your server. But but, there are blockers cutting this kind of information gathering short.