# How to implement remember me in JSP login page in Spring MVC?

Tags: javascript, hibernate, spring-mvc, jsp, cookies

I am new to Spring MVC and Cookies thing. I have a login JSP page, in that I am trying to implement a remember me checkbox. Through this a user, whosoever it may, not need to enter their login details every time. Login and password should be saved so that user get a flexibility to not to enter login details every time they visit the application login. I have written my login.jsp and AdminController class below. In AdminController class, I have found somewhere to add cookie thing to persist the login credentials of visitors. But, I have no idea how to implement this thing in my controller class. I have tried this below code but it is not working as expected. Any suggestions may appreciated.

```
<form action="verify" method="post" name="myform" onsubmit="return validateform()">
                    <p class="legend"> Login Here
                        <span class="fa fa-hand-o-down"></span>
                    </p>
                    <div class="input">
                        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Email or Phone Number" required="required"/>
                        <span class="fa fa-envelope"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input">
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required /> 
                        <span class="fa fa-unlock"></span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" name="Login" class="btn submit" value="Login"/>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember Me
                    </label>
                </form>

public User checkCookie(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        User account = null;
        String username = "", password = "";
        for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
            if (cookie.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("username")) {
                username = cookie.getValue();
                System.out.println("Username: "+username);
            }
            if (cookie.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("password")) {
                password = cookie.getValue();
            }
        }
        if (!username.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
            account = new User();
            System.out.println("User account: "+account);
        }
        return account;
    }
@RequestMapping(value = { UrlPath.adminlogin }, method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
    public ModelAndView adminlogin(HttpServletRequest request, User user, HttpSession session, HttpServletResponse response) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(UrlPath.adminlogin);
        User usermodel = checkCookie(request);
        if(usermodel == null) {
            modelAndView.addObject("user", new User());
            return modelAndView;
        } else {
            User newuser = new User();
            if(newuser.getUsername() != null && newuser.getPassword() != null) {
                session.setAttribute("username", usermodel.getUsername());
                if (request.getParameter("remember") != null) {
                Cookie ckUsername = new Cookie("username", usermodel.getUsername());
                ckUsername.setMaxAge(3600);
                response.addCookie(ckUsername);
                Cookie ckPassword = new Cookie("password", usermodel.getPassword());
                ckPassword.setMaxAge(3600);
                response.addCookie(ckPassword);
                }
            }
        }
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34851064/how-to-create-a-remember-me-function-in-login-without-using-form-in-javascript-o There are answers for your issue.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to implement those to get desired result.

Comment: Oky dr. If it is useful, mark above comment as an useful one.

Comment: Sure. I will do that.